# save value of spinner selected item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

How can I save the current selected spinner value, such that when I reopen the application the saved value is automatically selected by default?

Comment: Please see my answer and if it is helping you then please accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Please Write below code on `onItemSelectedListener()` of spinner and store selected value into shared preferences.

```
String mSpnValue=mSpinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
prefsEditor.putString("Value", mSpnValue);
```

Use below code for set item as selected in spinner.

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
String myString = myPrefs.getString("Value","nothing"); // the value you want the

ArrayAdapter<String> myAdap = (ArrayAdapter<String>) mSpinner1.getAdapter();
int spinnerPosition = myAdap.getPosition(myString);

// set the default according to value
mSpinner1.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
```

Comment: @user1673332 Where is your spinner?

Comment: @DipakKeshariya: It could be better if mSpnValue can hold getSelectedItemPosition instead of the getSelectedItem?

Comment: Don't forget "prefsEditor.commit()" or better "prefsEditor.apply()" after the line "prefsEditor.putString(...)".

Comment: this `toString()` doesn't work when you have a custom model set with your spinner adapter

Answer (score 1):

You can save spinner position in preferences and when entering back use `spinner.setSelection(position_from_preferences);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use several methods

For example you can use a DataBase and save on it.

Other methods, and the best IMO, is used SharedPreferences 
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/backup/SharedPreferencesBackupHelper.html

Answer (score 0):

For set value one another way:---

```
         for(int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++){
            if(adapter.getItem(i).equals(your save preference value){
                spinner_timer.setSelection(i);      
                }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also refer to the spinner value by position. that way you need only to deal with `ints` straight-fowardly:

```
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putInt("VALUE", spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
    editor.commit();
```

and to load:

```
spinner.setSelection(settings.getInt("VALUE", 0));
```